# Need solution to disable the taskbar at login

Tags: taskbar

Is there a registry hack to prevent running programs from appearing in the taskbar, or to disable and lock the taskbar at startup?

Comment: If you don't trust your users and need this kind of control over a general purpose computer, you're doing it wrong (tm).

Comment: welcome to SU - what OS is this for? Do you want to just selectively hide running applications in the taskbar, completely disable the taskbar altogether (including access to the Start menu) or do you want to effectively turn the computer into a kiosk?

Comment: @Daniel Beck: not if you want to write malware :)

Comment: thanx for the try, but you're enreasonable comment reveals your leack of intelegence,

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to remove Explorer entirely. You could change the Windows shell to a program other than `explorer.exe` (I think this is in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`), and then disable the task manager and run prompt (`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\DisableTaskMgr` and `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\NoRun`, I think) to prevent a user starting Explorer manually. You would need to replace the functionality of Explorer with your own software, although I assume you're already planning on doing this.